# Trigger BroadcastReceiver using Push Notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

How do I trigger broadcast as soon as I click on notification!?

Answer (score 0):

On the class extending GCMBaseIntentService in onMessage() call setNotificationMethod as below

```
private void setNotification(int defaults, String message, int flag) {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    int MOOD_NOTIFICATIONS = 12345;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // This method sets the defaults on the notification before posting it.
    Intent handleNotification = new Intent(this, PushNotifier.class);
    handleNotification.putExtra("Result", resultfrmServer);

    // This is who should be launched if the user selects our notification.
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            handleNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    final Notification notification = new Notification(
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, // the icon for the status bar
            message, // the text to display in the ticker
            System.currentTimeMillis()); // the timestamp for the
                                            // notification
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, // the context to use
            getText(R.string.app_name),
            // the title for the notification
            message, // the details to display in the notification
            contentIntent); // the contentIntent (see above)

    notification.defaults = defaults;

    notification.flags = flag;
    mNotificationManager.notify(MOOD_NOTIFICATIONS,notification);
}
```

Now when the notification is clicked PushNotifier class is started. Here you can decide whether you want to launch some other activity or register broadcast receiver. Also if you need information received in pushnotification you can send it to pushNotifier class using pending intent and user accordingly.